# With JPackage on Windows Is it possible to make main .exe not run as console, but have other laucher run as console?

Tags: java, java-14, jpackage

With JPackage I am unable to get --win-console option to work apart for for the main launcher, but I want the main launcher not to output to console, but have a debug version that does.

i.e if I run

```
jpackage --add-launcher SongKongDebug=jpackage.properties @jpackage.txt
```

**jpackage.txt**

```
-i C:\Code\jthink\SongKong\target\songkong-6.10
--runtime-image C:\code\jthink\songkong\JVM64
--main-class com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong
--name SongKong
--win-dir-chooser
--main-jar lib\SongKong-6.10.jar
--app-version 6.10
--install-dir Jthink\SongKong
--copyright "Copyright 2020 JThink Ltd, United Kingdom"
--license-file C:\Code\jthink\SongKong\src\main\scripts\license.txt
--java-options "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
--java-options "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
--java-options "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0"
--java-options "-XX:MetaspaceSize=45 "
--java-options "-Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.Jdk14MLog"
--java-options "-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=jdk"
--java-options "-Djava.util.logging.config.class=com.jthink.songkong.logging.StandardLogging"
--vendor JThink
--win-menu
--win-shortcut
--win-menu-group Jthink
```

**jpackage.properties**

```
win-console=--win-console
```

then both SongKong and SongKongDebug run without console

I also tried modifying jpackage.properties (whicch is meant to be name/value pairs) to

```
--win-console
```

and it still didnt work

Whereas if I add

```
--win-console
```

to jpackage.txt and

```
win-console
```

to jpackage.properties

then **SongKong** will run as console, and **SongKongDebug** will not, but is wrong way round for me.

If I rename **SongKong** to **SongKongDebug** and **SongKongDebug** to **SongKong**

e.g

```
jpackage --add-launcher SongKong=jpackage.properties @jpackage.txt
```

and modify
`set --name SongKongDebug`

in jpackage.txt

then it works but now when install SongKong it says installing **SongKongDebug** which is wrong.

I have tried both current Java 14 release and early access java 15 and 16 releases but makes no difference.

I found this bug reported, but then user closed it as no problem https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213717 and I find the jpackage help a bit confusing so I wonder if I am doing this the wrong way.

The help says

> Options for creating the application launcher(s):
>
> --add-launcher launcher name=file path
>
> ```
> Name of launcher, and a path to a Properties file that contains a list of key, value pairs (absolute path or relative to the current
> ```
>
> directory).
>
> ```
> The keys "module", "add-modules", "main-jar", "main-class", "arguments", "java-options", "app-version", "icon", and "win-console"
> ```
>
> can be used.
>
> ```
> These options are added to, or used to overwrite, the original command line options to build an additional alternative launcher. The
> ```
>
> main application launcher will be built from the command line options.
> Additional alternative launchers can be built using this option, and
> this option can be used multiple times to build multiple additional
> launchers.
> --arguments main class arguments
>
> ```
> Command line arguments to pass to the main class if no command line arguments are given to the launcher.
>
> This option can be used multiple times.
> ```
>
> --java-options java options
>
> ```
> Options to pass to the Java runtime.
>
> This option can be used multiple times.
> ```
>
> --main-class class name
>
> ```
> Qualified name of the application main class to execute.
>
> This option can only be used if --main-jar is specified.
> ```
>
> --main-jar main jar file
>
> ```
> The main JAR of the application; containing the main class (specified as a path relative to the input path).
>
> Either --module or --main-jar option can be specified but not both.
> ```
>
> --module or -m module name/main class]
>
> ```
> The main module (and optionally main class) of the application This module must be located on the module path.
>
> When this option is specified, the main module will be linked in the Java runtime image. Either --module or --main-jar option can be
> ```
>
> specified but not both.

So yo can create addtional launcher with the --add-launcher and use a properties file, but it also makes it sounds yo can can pass extra arguments as additional comand line options, but how could that be as it would not be clear which launcher they refer to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify console choice for each `--add-launcher` property file with  `win-console=true` or `win-console=false`:

**jpackage.properties**

```
 # This adds console for the current launcher:
 win-console=true
```

In the command line or arguments file `@jpackage.txt` the flag `--win-console` switches on the console for the main application and ALL `--add-launcher` files that don't specify `win-console=true|false`:

**@jpackage.txt**

```
# This adds console for all applications:
--win-console
```

Unfortunately jpackage has bug [JDK-8253426](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8253426) which prevents `--add-launcher` setting working with different `main-class=xyz` in JDK15.

Comment: Hmm, my main exe used to be SongKong64.exe so I could have SongKong SongKong64 and SongKongDebug but difficult to explain to user to use SongKong64 rather than SongKong, can I have only SongKong64 being added within Porgrams and Features

Comment: Thanks I upgraded to Java 17, I removed reference to --win-console from jpackage.txt, I added win-console=true to jpackage.properties, and then run jpackage --add-launcher SongKongDebug=jpackage.properties @jpackage.txt . That now works, not sure if I was doing it wrong before or if there was a bug in jpackage that is now fixed.